# Holding pixel data in NSMutableArray/NSArray; memory issues

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to hold basic information about a pixel inside an object. Basically, (1) whether the pixel is clear and (2) whether the pixel is on what I am defining to be a surface edge. I'm using the following class to define the object:

```
@interface PixelInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isClear;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isEdge;
@end
```

However, I'm running into low memory issues. I'm using this object to keep track of the state of a pixel in a game that has a destructible environment. The problem may be that for an iPad retina sized image (2048 x 1536 = 3 million pixels), I am creating 3 million of these objects and seems to be allocating hundreds of MB of memory, and is causing an iPhone device to force quit due to low memory issues.

Looking at the logs inside the iPhone device, I'm getting the following information:

```
Name     rpages     recent_max     [reason]             (state)       
MyApp    166400     166400         [per-process-limit]  (frontmost) (resume)
```

Using Instruments Allocations tool, I see hundreds of MB of memory being allocated to PixelInfo objects over time, until eventually, the iPhone device force quits.

Based on this, I'm guessing maybe I should not be holding pixel information like this. I'm also suspicious that Instruments Allocations is showing that the device is needing hundreds of MB of memory to accomplish this. Something may be going wrong elsewhere, but I can't seem to pinpoint it.

I do feel the need to keep track of the state of all the pixels. I'm using this pixel information to track the state of the image when I am destroying the environment (i.e., setting pixel info `isClear` property to YES, and `isEdge` property to NO), then to recalculate the new edges for the affected portion of the environment.

Here are my main questions:

1. Is it bad that I am attempting to hold 3 million objects inside an array?
2. Low memory is clearly a problem (seen using the Instruments Allocations tool), but is it correct that hundreds of MB of memory needs to be used by these 3 million objects or is it likely that something else is causing issues?

Any thoughts or pointers on how I should debug this situation further would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

--
Just for additional context (if relevant), this is how I am reading and storing pixel information from a texture (using some cocos2d classes):

```
unsigned char data[4];

// create texture to read pixel data from
CCRenderTexture *renderTexture = [[CCRenderTexture alloc] initWithWidth:widthInPoints
                                                                 height:heightInPoints
                                                            pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
[renderTexture beginWithClear:1 g:1 b:1 a:0];

// self.view is a CCSprite object and the visit method draws it to the texture so I can read the pixels
[self.view visit];

for (int i = 0; i < heightInPixels; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < widthInPixels; ++j) {

        // read pixel data
        CGPoint pixelPoint = ccp(j, i);
        glReadPixels(pixelPoint.x, pixelPoint.y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

        // store pixel data in PixelInfo object; read alpha value in data
        PixelInfo *pixelInfo = [[PixelInfo alloc] init];
        pixelInfo.isClear = [self _isPixelClear:data];

        // add object to _pixelData array (NSMutableArray object)
        [_pixelData addObject:pixelInfo];
        [pixelInfo release];            
    }
}

// release texture
[renderTexture end];
[renderTexture release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to decrease your memory usage, use two boolean array instead of an array containing instances of objects with two booleans

Comment: an instance of your PixelInfo class has a memory size superior to the size of your two booleans, so working with two boolean arrays is much lighter and use less CPU

Comment: Looking at memory allocated for each PixelInfo object was definitely at the heart of the problem. I will try converting the implementation to two boolean arrays when I'm home tonight. Thanks!

Comment: to further decrease your memory usage, you can also use only one array of unsigned char and use masks to set / retrieve your two boolean values

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that you're storing 3 million PixelInfo objects inside an NSArray. (3 million * (4 + 1 + 1) bytes, assuming 4 bytes for NSObject.isa and 1 byte each for BOOL is only 18 MB). 
 At least from the code you've posted, it appears that the problem is that you only add PixelInfo objects to the NSArray, but never release them. If you add 3 million objects into the array for each rendered frame, at 30fps, you could end up with 540MB (18MB * 30) of memory allocated per second. You can see how this could very quickly lead to the memory issues you're seeing.
 Without knowing too many details, one suggestion for improvement is to create a single array of shorts and update the appropriate values in this array, instead of continuously creating new objects and storing them. 
 To illustrate: 
`short *pixelInfo = (short *) calloc(1, sizeof(short) * heightInPixels * widthInPixels); // use calloc to zero-fill the bytes`
`...`
 `pixelInfo[i*heightInPixels+j] |= [self _isPixelClear: data]; // set isClear`
`pixelInfo[i*heightInPixels+j] |= [self _isPixelEdge: data] << 1; // set isEdge`
 `pixelInfo[i*heightInPixels+j] & 0x1; // isClear set?` 
 `(pixelInfo[i*heightInPixels+j] >> 1) & 0x1; // isEdge set?` 
 
 Of course, with this approach, you'll need to clear the pixel-info's between frames if this info does not persist across frames. 
 If you can articulate your needs in a little more detail, more specific/better suggestions could come up.

Comment: because of memory alignment, stating that a PixelInfo instance weight 6 bytes is way too much naive, two BOOL are much like 8 bytes, furthermore, with ARC there is not need of putting release instruction, we do not see the array allocation, so how can you assume he neither release it after having worked on it ?

Comment: another thing you didn't take into account, for a PixelInfo instance, you must also think of the pointer stored inside the array that references it, a pointer if 4 byte long on ARM

Comment: Thanks, I've never really had to consider memory overhead in allocating objects. This was definitely a major problem in my implementation.

Comment: To clarify a bit, I'm keeping this array of 3 million objects allocated over the duration of the game. I'm not allocating any more. Checking Instrument Leaks tool, I don't think leaks are an issue. I'm using non-ARC. My strategy will be to stop using the PixelInfo object I'm using now and use much smaller storage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a bit array. One such implementation by Michael Dipperstein can be [found here](http://michael.dipperstein.com/bitlibs/). The C version is included in [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) and [KoboldTouch](http://www.koboldtouch.com).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting bit arrays. It definitely appears I need to minimize the memory footprint as much as possible. I'll have to look into this as I'm not familiar with bit arrays.

Comment: Also think outside pixels.I mean on Retina you could store the information for 4 pixels and you'd have the same logical density as on non Retina.

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion. I would need to change my implementation slightly to do this but it may make more sense.

Comment: I also wanted to update you on switching over from objects to bit arrays. I ended up using std::bitset -- since I'm already using objective-c++ (due to using Box2D) in my project, I thought it made sense. Using Instruments Allocations tool, the memory footprint went from hundreds of MB to not really noticeable (!). Since I have 2048*1536 = 3,145,728 pixels (iPad retina resolution) and I have 2 bools I want to keep track of for each pixel, I assume the new memory footprint is ~ 3,145,728 * 2 bits = 768 KB. Thanks again!!